# Return object has condition true from object has key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I have question about object. I want to `filter` to return list of keys has condition true in this object below:

```
myObject = {
   key1: {
     name:"key1",
     select:true
   },
   key2: {
     name:"key2",
     select:false
   },
   key3: {
     name:"key3",
     select:true
   }
}
```

For some reason, I have to add specific key for it. Now I want to return an array has seclect `true`.

```
arrayWantreturn = ["key1", "key3"]
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following:

```js
const myObject = {
   key1: {
     name:"key1",
     select:true
   },
   key2: {
     name:"key2",
     select:false
   },
   key3: {
     name:"key3",
     select:true
   }
};

const result = Object.entries(myObject)
                     .filter(([k, v]) => v['select'])
                     .flatMap(e => e[1].name);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of your object using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and then keep all of the objects which have a `select` of `true` by using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You can then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each remaining object to its name property like so:

```js
const myObject = { key1: { name:"key1", select:true }, key2: { name:"key2", select:false }, key3: { name:"key3", select:true } };
const res = Object.values(myObject)
              .filter(({select}) => select)
              .map(({name}) => name); 
      
console.log(res);
```

This uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the property values in the callback method arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop with that object:

```js
var myObject = {
   key1: {
     name:"key1",
     select:true
   },
   key2: {
     name:"key2",
     select:false
   },
   key3: {
     name:"key3",
     select:true
   }
};

var arr = [];

for (var prop in myObject) {
    if (myObject[prop].select) {
        arr.push(myObject[prop].name);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```